# Finding angle with geometric approach

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I would like to solve the problem in this picture:

[image: this picture]

with just an elementary geometric approach. I already solved with trigonometry, e.g. using the Bretschneider formula, finding that the angle $ x = 15° $. Any idea?

This is how I computed the $ x $ value using the Bretschneider formula for the area of the quadrilateral $ ABDE $ and equating to the sum of the triangles' area $ ABE + EFD + BDF $

$$\begin{cases}
BC = a \\
AB = a(1/\tan(2x) - 1) \\
BD = a\sqrt{2} \\
AE = AB/\cos(2x+\pi/6) = a(1/\tan(2x) -1)/\cos(2x+\pi/6) \\
ED = a/\cos(x)
\end{cases}
$$

So I solved this equation with Mathematica, and the only solution that fit the problem is $ x = \pi/12 $

$ a^2/2+(a^2(1/\tan(2x) - 1)(1+\tan(x)))/2 + a^2 \tan(x)/2 =
((a\sqrt{2})^2 + \\
(a(1/\tan(2x)- 1)/\cos(2x+\pi/6))^2 - (a/\cos(x))^2 -(a(1/\tan(2x) - 1))^2)/4 \tan(\pi/2 -2x) $

I guess there is a simpler trigonometric approach, but I just wanted to try with that formula.

Comment: What is the research angle to your question?

Comment: @WlodAA is the angle EDF

Comment: Calling EDF the "research angle" of this question reminds me of the old joke about "finding x" (and a student pointing out "here it is").

Comment: @JukkaKohonen 

Comment: But seriously: Trigonometric functions are an overkill and not needed at all here. You can solve it by elementary observations of sums and differences of angles. As such the problem is quite off-topic on MO, and will likely be closed. (Perhaps you meant to post it on Math StackExchange instead?)

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I guess you are right about the use of trigonometric functions, and of course there is a geometric demonstration. Yeah, I already tried on Math Stackexchange and a plain geometric proof was given, but there was still something missing https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623615/finding-angle-with-geometric-approach

Comment: Oops, on a second thought, I guess simple sums and differences of angles are not enough. Perhaps (some) trigononometric functions are the best approach after all. (Still not research-level though.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is elementary enough, though the exercise could fit in an Olympiad style easily. So here is another analytic way. In the figure, let the point $D$ be the center $(0;0)$ and assume that the sides of the square are of unit length. So you get $C(1;0)$, $B(1;1)$, $A(1;\tan(X))$, $G(\frac{1}{\tan(X)};1)$.

Here we should bound $X$ so the problem has a meaning. If $E'$ is the symmetric of $E$ with respect to $F(0;1)$, your problem is equivalent to the following equation in $X$ (which characterises the angle bisector $(DE')$ in the triangle $DFG$):
$$(1)\quad\dfrac{DG}{DF}=\dfrac{E'G}{E'F}.$$
Finding the line $(EA)$ as $$y=\tan(X-\frac{\pi}{6})x+\tan(X)-\tan(X-\frac{\pi}{6}),$$ then $E\left(\dfrac{1+\tan(X-\frac{\pi}{6})-\tan(X)}{\tan(X-\frac{\pi}{6})};1\right).$
Putting this in $(1)$, squaring both sides expanding and simplifying, you get the equation $$(2\sqrt{3}+1)t^4- (2\sqrt{3}+4)t^3-4t^2+ (6\sqrt{3}-4)t-2\sqrt{3}+3=0,$$
where $t=\tan(X)$. A root is $t=\sqrt{3}$, the other roots are not acceptable from the figure condition on $X$, for example $x_E<0$ etc. (I guess this may be also made elementary).[image]

Comment: Thank you for your proof. I still would prefer to use just geometric considerations. I tried to post here too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623615/finding-angle-with-geometric-approach and a proof was given, but still miss something (specifically why the square side is equal to the circle radius)

Comment: Yes i guess a short proof  like that is not a complete one. There shoud be some calculation. Where the problem comes from? If may i ask.

Comment: Oh well from a FB group. If you are interested you can answer on Math Stackexchange too, because I guess the question on here will be closed